# How to change logo on invoices in Acumatica ERP

Tags: acumatica, erp

Can somebody tell me a few hints ( steps ) about how i can change the company logo on invoices issued with Acumatica ERP . Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

In the report you need to ensure that there is a picture box element (in the group header section not in the page header section, otherwise it will not work) Then ensure that the following properties are set:

- MimeType: image/gif
- Source: Database
- Value: =[Branch.BranchOrOrganizationLogoNameReport]

After that you need to set the logo for the company in Acumatica, in order to do this go to the companies screen and upload the logo in the "Report Logo" section under the "Visual Appearance" tab. This can also be done per branch, in the Branches screen.

Comment: Thank you sir, your information were very helpful, i must mention i'm totally newbie in acumatica or coding.
I have two short question:
1. if i want to change my OLD logo picture from invoices / shipment information , ... all i have to do is to upload the NEW logo ( png file ) in section Branches -> Logo ?
2. Can i use any type of image  ? PNG is ok ? pictures :  [link](http://itmax.ro/branches_2.jpg)]      [link](http://itmax.ro/report_designer_2.jpg)

Comment: Yes if you change the logo in the branches section when you go to view the old invoices they will use the new logo. PNG images should work fine for the logo as well I believe